# Date Picker Layout View

Tags: android

I have to implement the date picker in my layout. 
I have to show the date picker with plus minus symbol.

but after implementing date picker in my xml , I got the date picker having previous an next date above and below.

Please  let me know that how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you are testing in latest android version i.e. above API Level 11, so if you need to show the old widgets or UI elements then please add:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
```

in your current `<activity>` in AndroidManifest file.